# How to stop on click event?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

How can I stop a on click event that was `prepossessed` 
So I used the code given below,

```
function hide() {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
    }
<input type="submit" value="select services" onclick="hide()" style="border: none; background: transparent; width: 95px;" />
        <div class="dss" id="demo">
            <ul style="list-style: none;">
                <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, this is very unclear. It is also not formatted very well.

Comment: Could you add more information? What did you mean with "preprossesed"?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function hide() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
}

function show() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
}

function removeOnClick() {
    document.getElementById("hideButton").onclick = function() {};
}

function addOnClick() {
    document.getElementById("hideButton").onclick = hide;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="select services" onclick="hide()" style="border: none; background: transparent; width: 95px;" id="hideButton"/>
<div class="dss" id="demo">
  <ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input type="submit" onclick="show()" value="show services"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="removeOnClick()" value="remove on click"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="addOnClick()" value="add on click"/>
```

The function removeOnClick when called will set the onclick method of your original submit button to a blank function. Also this can only be done by giving an Id to your original submit input.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but I'm assuming you're trying to cancel the default event.

First: please verify whether you need `<input type="submit">` or `<input type="button">`. I cannot tell because I do not have all of the context.

Secondly, it is not great practice to inline event handlers or CSS.

Add an ID to your button, and then add an event handler with javascript, and style it with CSS.

```
<style>
    #selectbtn {
        border: none;
        background: transparent;
        width: 95px;
    }
</style>

<input type="button" id="selectbtn" value="select services" />
<div class="dss" id="demo">
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    var selectbtn = document.getElementById("selectbtn");
    selectbtn.addEventHandler("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault()  // prevents the default event from taking place
        // code here ...

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="submit" value="select services" onclick="hide(); return false;" style="border: none; background: transparent; width: 95px;" />
```

**`return false;`** after function call.

Answer (score 0):

`return false` after calling function as below:

```
<input type='submit'onclick="hide(); return false;">
```